# How to use functions with WHERE in SAS?

Tags: sas

I am new to SAS. I was trying to print only rows where the string size is less than 20, for the column words. I tried this, but that doesn't work. What is the right syntax?

```
FILENAME REFFILE '<path_to_the_file>';
...
PROC PRINT DATA=WORK.IMPORT;
  WHERE length("words") < 20;
RUN;
```

This is the error I get

```
ERROR: Invalid characters were present in the data.
ERROR: An error occurred while processing text data.
```

I don't think there is any problem with the data itself, as the following works fine.

```
PROC PRINT DATA=WORK.IMPORT;
  WHERE words = "some string";
RUN;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out, the problem was not with the code itself, but because I did not specify the encoding. So instead of

```
FILENAME REFFILE '<path_to_the_file>';
```

I used the following, which worked.

```
FILENAME REFFILE '<path_to_the_file>' encoding="latin1";
```